# Dataset of microscopic images before and after staining?

Tags: microscopy, database

I am looking for a freely distributed dataset of microscopic images. I am hoping to find a dataset that would feature histological images before and after staining (e.g. H&E or some other standard one, preferably). I have been searching through various databases, but I cannot find a proper set. I hope the sample size to be at least about 100. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean, *"before and after staining"*? An image taken before staining won't show anything...

Comment: Oh, I must have understood something incorrectly. Well, I hope I can have access to the "raw" data, as well as the processed versions.

Comment: There should be very minimal processing for scientific images - otherwise you are not looking at true results.

Comment: Do you have a particular species in mind? are you looking for something like this? (http://www.virtualflybrain.org/site/stacks/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Virtual fly brain (http://www.virtualflybrain.org/site/stacks/index.htm) is an excellent database of fly (*Drosophila*) brain sections, which can be electronically processed/annotated/highlighted on the fly to show different areas of the fly brain as an overlay on top of the original images.

Alternatively, you can use BrainTrap (http://fruitfly.inf.ed.ac.uk/braintrap/) for the expression of proteins in the fly (*Drosophila*) brain using brain sections. Another database which has silver stains of *Drosophila* brain sections is the flybrain (http://flybrain.neurobio.arizona.edu/Flybrain/html/atlas/) database. This database also contains 3D models of different fly brain structures and much more!

I'm sure there are many many similar databases, but these are the ones I knew of, which are widely used in the *Drosophila* community.