# Is there a database of cell images?

Tags: cell-biology, bioinformatics, database

We're working on an algorithm for processing images of cells, similar to but much more basic than [Cell Profiler](http://www.cellprofiler.org/), and we are looking for a large database of cell images to test our software. Can anyone point us in the right direction? We found the Cell Image Library immediately, but it seems almost empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good sources of free-to-use images and diagrams](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/what-are-good-sources-of-free-to-use-images-and-diagrams) and http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38774/open-database-of-medical-images and [dataset of microscopic images before and after staining](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20284/dataset-of-microscopic-images-before-and-after-staining)

Comment: The ATCC website has a bunch of images of cells in culture.

Comment: @AMR those are not duplicate questions. I vote to leave open as it looks like a valid question to me.

Comment: @AliceD That is your call, but all three have links to cell image libraries. The point of flagging as a duplicate question is also to show where a simple search of the stack would have yielded acceptable answers to the question. Answer in first link leads to Wellcome Images which has a large set of cellular images of all types. The second link had this comment https://www.nlm.nih.gov/NIHbmic/nih_data_sharing_repositories.html and the third is pretty much an identical question, with the sole exception that they did not specify it was for bioinformatics.

Comment: @AMR - admittedly, I didn't check the answers in your links, but then, as far as I understand SE's policy, I don't think questions should be closed because the answers are out there as sidelong answers posted to unrelated questions. If that would be so, a great many questions could be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a yearly contest on cell tracking organized by the IEEE International Symposium on Biomedical Imaging, and the associated data sets are freely available.

See for example: http://www.celltrackingchallenge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I've actually answered my own question. The creators of Cell Profiler mentioned a database of biological images which they used to benchmark their software, and it appears to be available at http://www.broadinstitute.org/bbbc/